# Сжать картинку в JPEG с потерями качества C++

Tags: c++, jpeg

Решил написать забавы ради и интереса приложение на С++, которое будет "Шакалить" изображения. Нашел хорошое решение на OpenCV, но слишком уж громоздко, только собирал его час на 40%, дальше не стал...

Подскажите, есть какие-либо другие либы для "Шакализации", т.е. сжатия по алгоритму JPEG.

Comment: Классика - это [libjpeg](https://github.com/md81544/libjpeg_cpp)

Comment: Благодарю, выручили)